# My keyboard stopped repeating - how to fix?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have both an internal and external keyboard but the key-repeat has stopped working.  I've tried changing both 'Key Repeat' and 'Delay Until Repeat' as shown below but no setting seems to be helping.

[image]

This is a brand new mac (5 weeks old).

Comment: What OS are your using? Did you recently upgrade to Lion/Mountain Lion? What computer model are you using?

Comment: updated with the fact it is new

Comment: And repeat used to work, but now it doesn't?

Comment: Try this command: `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: I have the same problem, and my Mac is new from 3 days ! I have Mavericks. Key repeating was working, but not fast enough to my taste. So I went to the Keyboard System Prefs, and now key repeating has stopped working.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco  Did you get the key repeating issue resolved? Actually I am on El Capitan now.

Comment: I can confirm that key repeat is not working on this 13" MBP, 1 week old, El Capitan, 10.11.3.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well it looks like there are a couple solutions:

**Option 1.** Enter this in terminal: `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`. To disable repeating keys again, enter the same command except change the `false` to `true`.

**Option 2.** [Download Mountain Tweaks](http://tweaksapp.com/app/mountain-tweaks/) (I assume you're on Mountain Lion, if not, download [Lion Tweaks](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39654/lion-tweaks/)) and click the "Yes" option for "Enable Repeating Keys":

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to *reload applications* you use so as to allow this feature to take effect. They don't catch this option "on fly" quite often

Comment: application restart is definitely necessary

Comment: Weird that tinkering with 'Key Repeat' speed in sys prefs didn't fix this. But the line of code in terminal did, for me anyway.

Comment: FYI the restart is not necessary in BigSur, also this is an insane setting.....

Answer (score 17):

If running

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

seems to have no effect, try a restart. This seems to be necessary in more recent versions of OS X.

Comment: In my case it was enough to type "exit" in the terminal. That seems to have enabled the option globally.

Comment: {on Mojave) This works immediately in the terminal where the command was issued, but applications (Firefox, Word, etc.) need to be restarted for key repeat to work.

Answer (score 7):

By default, on macOS (since at least OS X Lion), when you hold down a key, it will display a popup allowing you pick a special character if there are any assigned to that particular key:
[image: special char popup]

If a key doesn’t have any special characters behind it and you hold it down, **nothing will happen**.

As stated in Apple's docs:

> You can add accent marks and special characters to some letters. For example, click and hold the a key to type à, á, â or other characters.
>
> If you set the Key Repeat slider to Off, special characters won’t appear when you hold down a key.

[Set how quickly a key repeats on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchl0311bdb4/mac#:%7E:text=If%20you%20press%20and%20hold,key%27s%20character%20begins%20to%20repeat.&text=On%20your%20Mac%2C%20choose%20Apple,before%20the%20character%20begins%20repeating)

To disable special characters popup and return traditional behaviour with key repeat, run following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Then restart applications (or computer) to update settings.